# How to set Page Layout margins in borb 2.1.16

Tags: python, pdf, layoutmargins, borb

How is the right way to set Page Layout margin now?
In borb 2.1.15 works properly and in examples is some like this too:

```
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout

# create an empty PDF
doc: Document = Document()

# create an empty Page
page: Page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

# set a PageLayout
layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page, horizontal_margin=Decimal(50), vertical_margin=Decimal(50))
```

But in actual `borb 2.1.16` this does not work.

I tried `w=` and `h=` but still not lucky.

Answer (score 2):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`.

At some point, the signature of `SingleColumnLayout` changed to be more consistent with the other `LayoutElement` objects. You can either use `SingleColumnLayout` (which does not allow you to set these parameters), or you can use `MultiColumnLayout` (from which `SingleColumnLayout` inherits).

`MultiColumnLayout` has the following (default) parameters:

```py
margin_bottom: Decimal = Decimal(84.2),
margin_left: Decimal = Decimal(59.5),
margin_right: Decimal = Decimal(59.5),
margin_top: Decimal = Decimal(84.2),
```

Your complete example would become:

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import MultiColumnLayout

# create an empty PDF
doc: Document = Document()

# create an empty Page
page: Page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

# get Page width
w: typing.Optional[Decimal] = page.get_page_info().get_width()
assert w is not None

# set a PageLayout
layout: PageLayout = MultiColumnLayout(page, 
                                       column_widths=[w - Decimal(100)], 
                                       margin_top=Decimal(50), 
                                       margin_right=Decimal(50),
                                       margin_bottom=Decimal(50),
                                       margin_left=Decimal(50),
                                       )
```